# Which of these is the best practice for web sockets in terms of performance?

Tags: performance, websocket, socket.io

This is more of a hypothetical question, so I can't really show any code examples. Imagine if a site like Twitter wanted to live-update stats on a Tweet via web sockets/Socket.io. In terms of performance, which of these would be the best approach?

1. Each action (like, retweet, reply) sends a message to the server, which then gets emitted to *all* clients, and the client is responsible for updating the appropriate tweet.
2. Each tweet the client loads is connected to a different room so that it only emits and receives messages relevant to itself.
3. Other?

Or perhaps it's dependent on the scale of the application? Maybe 1 is better if you had a Twitter clone with only a few users, whereas I would think 2 is better in Twitter's case because it's a matter of hundreds of "rooms" vs *millions* of signals/second? And if that's the case, at what point is one approach preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At scale, you do not want to be sending messages to clients that they did not ask for and do not have any use for.  Imagine a twitter client that was receiving every single tweet being sent in real time.  That could overwhelm that client and it would mean the server would be delivering every single tweet to every single connected client.  That obviously doesn't scale on either the server side or the client side.

So option 1 is out.

---

The appropriate solution has the server send to the client only the messages that is has a particular interest in seeing.  This works just fine at any scale.  I can't tell whether your option 2 is that or not since rooms are just a tool for making groups of connections that you can send the same message to - they don't really decide who gets what message - that logic must be baked into your server code.

For a twitter-like service, it seems you're going to have to have a system where your server can easily tell which users have an interest in this particular new message.  That can presumably be for a number of reasons such as they are following the author, they are following a hashtag present in the message, they are mentioned in the message, etc...  That is server-side logic, not just simple rooms.